# How to remove mean of a Keras layer, like Batchnormalization, without considering variance?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, normalization, centering, batch-normalization

I want to do what BatchNormalization layer does in Keras, of removing the mean and storing a moving average. Unfortunately, the [BatchNormalization layer in Keras](https://keras.io/api/layers/normalization_layers/batch_normalization/) always considers the variance too, and I don't want to use it.

I was thinking on using Average and Subtract layers, but they don't store anything for usage when training has ended. The idea is that my layer removes and learn the mean, so when predicting on test, it subtracts a constant value.

Answer (score 1):

I created a `Centering` layer to do this, copied from `BatchNormalization` [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.1/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/normalization.py). It uses momentum to move the current moving mean value. It seems to work and I can save and load models with it.

```py
from tensorflow.keras import backend
from tensorflow.keras import initializers
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow import math
from tensorflow.python.distribute import distribution_strategy_context
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import tf_utils
from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import math_ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import state_ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import variables


class Centering(layers.Layer):
    """Layer that centers the data learning a mean."""

    def __init__(self, momentum=0.01, **kwargs):
        """Constructor of LatentProjection."""
        if 'input_shape' not in kwargs and 'input_dim' in kwargs:
            kwargs['input_shape'] = (kwargs.pop('input_dim'),)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.input_spec = layers.InputSpec(min_ndim=2)
        self.momentum = momentum
        self.moving_mean = None

    def build(self, input_shape):
        """Create internal variables."""
        assert len(input_shape) >= 2
        input_dim = input_shape[-1]
        self.moving_mean = self.add_weight(
            name='moving_mean',
            shape=(input_dim,),
            initializer=initializers.Zeros,
            synchronization=variables.VariableSynchronization.ON_READ,
            trainable=False,
            aggregation=variables.VariableAggregation.MEAN,
            experimental_autocast=False)
        self.input_spec = layers.InputSpec(min_ndim=2, axes={-1: input_dim})
        self.built = True

    def _get_training_value(self, training=None):
        """Copied from normalization.py."""
        if training is None:
            training = backend.learning_phase()
        if isinstance(training, int):
            training = bool(training)
        if not self.trainable:
            # When the layer is not trainable, it overrides the value
            # passed from model.
            training = False
        return training

    def _support_zero_size_input(self):
        """Copied from normalization.py."""
        return distribution_strategy_context.has_strategy() and getattr(
            distribution_strategy_context.get_strategy().extended,
            'experimental_enable_get_next_as_optional', False)

    def _assign_moving_average(self, variable, value, momentum, inputs_size):
        """Copied from normalization.py."""
        with backend.name_scope('AssignMovingAvg') as scope:
            with ops.colocate_with(variable):
                decay = ops.convert_to_tensor_v2(1.0 - momentum, name='decay')
                if decay.dtype != variable.dtype.base_dtype:
                    decay = math_ops.cast(decay, variable.dtype.base_dtype)
                update_delta = (variable -
                                math_ops.cast(value, variable.dtype)) * decay
                if inputs_size is not None:
                    update_delta = array_ops.where(
                        inputs_size > 0, update_delta,
                        backend.zeros_like(update_delta))
                return state_ops.assign_sub(variable, update_delta, name=scope)

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, **kwargs):
        """Called for each mini batch when applied to input layer."""
        training = self._get_training_value(training)
        training_value = tf_utils.constant_value(training)
        if training_value == False:
            mean = self.moving_mean
        else:
            mean = math.reduce_mean(inputs, axis=0)
            # Following code copied from normalization.py to update moving mean
            if self._support_zero_size_input():
                # Keras assumes that batch dimension is the first dimension for
                # Batch Normalization.
                input_batch_size = array_ops.shape(inputs)[0]
            else:
                input_batch_size = None

            def mean_update():
                """Perform update of moving mean average using copied code."""
                self._assign_moving_average(
                    self.moving_mean, mean, self.momentum, input_batch_size)
            self.add_update(mean_update)
        # Center inputs
        return inputs - mean

    def get_config(self):
        """Internal config of this layer."""
        config = {
            'momentum': self.momentum,
        }
        base_config = super().get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also disable scaling in BatchNormalization

gamma is a learned scaling factor (initialized as 1), which can be disabled by passing scale=False to the constructor.

Comment: I think in that case, the input is divided by moving mean sampling variance, even if the output is not multiplied by a factor.